# Hide custom posts after past certain date

Tags: php, post, acfpro

I have an Elementor site using ACF to create a custom post called coach-tour. Within the custom post I have created a date-picker field called trip_departure_date

I have these listed in a loop grid and ordered in date order (soonest first) using this PHP code:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/trip_sorted_by_date', function( $query ) {

  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'trip_departure_date' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

});
```

Is there a way to modify this code so that only posts that occur after todays date are displayed. i.e. when trip departure date is passed, those posts will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Add condition :

```
$today = date('Ymd'); // Get today's date in the same format as your date picker

$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'trip_departure_date',
        'value'   => $today,
        'compare' => '>=', // Only show posts with departure date today or in the future
        'type'    => 'DATE' // Ensure the type is set to DATE for proper comparison
    )
);

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

Comment: Excellent - du bist der Hammer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be helpful if you could please provide an explanation outside of your code block to offer context for your solution. Explanations are harder to read when they are embedded only within code blocks.